# calculating border radius for a small width with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a slider for progress

if say it's at 1% how can I calculate the right px/% for the border-radius?

when it's a big % it looks good

```html
<div style="background: grey; height: 25px; border-radius: 12.5px; width: 100%">
  <div style="background: green; height: 25px; border-radius: 12.5px; width: 15%" />
</div>
```

when it's small like 1% it looks like this

```html
<div style="background: grey; height: 25px; border-radius: 12.5px; width: 100%">
  <div style="background: green; height: 25px; border-radius: 12.5px; width: 1%" />
</div>
```

Comment: A 1% is supposed to look small in my opinion.  just add `overflow: hidden` to your parent div, then that should look better.

Answer (score 2):

try adding:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

for your green filler. It will hide inside the container. What you're trying to do is close to impossible. Can you imagine adding a `border-radius` on an element that is `< 2px` in `width`?

```html
<div style="background: grey; 
            height: 25px; 
            border-radius: 12.5px; 
            width: 100%; 
            overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="background: green; 
              height: 25px; 
              border-radius: 12.5px; 
              width: 1%" />
</div>
```

Comment: Using this method, you can remove the `border-radius` from the green filler altogether.

Comment: I presume he still wants the filler to be circular or to have radius as it slides through.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

A 1% is supposed to look small in my opinion. just add `overflow: hidden` to your parent div, then that should look better.

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden; background: grey; height: 25px; border-radius: 12.5px; width: 100%">
  <div style="background: green; height: 25px; border-radius: 12.5px; width: 1%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to completely keep the radius of the progress bar, you may try cloning a same element as the progress bar container and set its `left`.

This example is working with Javascript or you may use pure css only by editing its `left`.

Please see if this is your another good choice as well.

```js
set_progress(2); // percentage of progress

function set_progress(p) {
  $('.progress-container span').css('left', (p-100)+'%');
}
```

```css
.progress-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress-container > span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #0c0;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-container">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are losing the border-radius because you are altering the `width` of your green progress element.

Instead, if you set the green div to the same 100% width, you can represent the progress by using CSS transform to move the green div to the left.

```
transform: translateX(-90%);
```

This is the value you want to change to update the progress, use inverse value, so -90% is really 10% of progress (100 - 10 = 90) and so on.

Use `overflow: hidden;` on the outer div to hide the extra green.

```css
.progress-bar {
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the green that overflows */
  background: grey;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
}

.progress {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; /* same width as outer div */
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  transform: translateX(-90%); /* this is the value you want to change to update the progress, use inverse value, so -90% is really 10% of progress (100 - 10 = 90) */
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```